# Button becomes enabled on RESET but shouldn't

Tags: jquery

I have a select list and based on that I made the button disabled unless a valid option is chosen, which works fine but if I hit the "reset" button in the form the "submit" button becomes enabled but it should be disabled still (since the first option has the value of "").

How can I remedy this?

Thanks

jquery:

```
if ($("li#modFilterField_34 select").val() == "") {
        $('.search input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }


    $("li#modFilterField_34 select").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "Paintings" ) {

            $('.search input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');


        } else if ($(this).val() == "Houses" ) {

           $('.search input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');

        } else {

            $('.search input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
```

html:

```
    <form id="modMtFilterForm0" name="modMtFilterForm0" method="get" action="/oljadir/index.php">

        <ul class="modMtFilter" id="modMtFilter0">
        <li class="mfieldtype_selectlist" id="modFilterField_34">
<label>Choose type*:</label>
<span class="filterinput"><select class="inputbox text_area" name="cf34">
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="Paintings">Paintings</option>
<option value="Houses">Houses</option>
</select>
</span></li>

<li class="mfieldtype_corename" id="modFilterField_1"><label>Name:</label><span class="filterinput"><input type="text" size="50" id="filter_cf1" name="link_name" class="inputbox text_area"></span></li><li class="mfieldtype_mcheckbox" id="modFilterField_33"><label>Ostalo::</label><span class="filterinput"><ul style="margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none"><li><input type="checkbox" id="filter_cf33_0" value="KTV" name="cf33[]"><label for="filter_cf33_0">KTV</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" id="filter_cf33_1" value="Internet" name="cf33[]"><label for="filter_cf33_1">Internet</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" id="filter_cf33_2" value="Prevoz" name="cf33[]"><label for="filter_cf33_2">Prevoz</label></li></ul></span></li>        <li class="button-send"><input type="submit" onclick="javascript:var cookie = document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i &lt; cookie.length;i++) {var c = cookie[i];while (c.charAt(0)==' '){c = c.substring(1,c.length);}var name = c.split('=')[0];if( name.substr(0,35) == 'com_mtree_mfields_searchFieldValue_'){document.cookie = name + '=;';}}" value="Search" disabled="disabled"></li>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>


        </ul>

    </form>
```

Comment: Where is the code for your reset button?

Comment: no code, just a html button with the type of reset.

Comment: Can you please add the markup as well? What's the `form` structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this myself with the help of Moses and Moby's responses (it gave me the idea).

```
$('.search button[type="reset"]').click( function() {

    $('.search input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is attach a `reset` event handler to your `form` element and disable the element again if needed. For this I will need to see your HTML or I could just give you a general example.

**EDIT:**

BTW, it's better to use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in cases such as these instead of `attr`.

i.e.

```
$('#modMtFilterForm0').on('reset', function() {
    $("li#modFilterField_34 select").val('');
    $('.search input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: With this I have to click reset twice, because select does not have value of "" originally. I actually solved it myself with the idea I got from this and moby's response.

Comment: As long as you've found what you were looking for, all is good :)
I'll update my answer to fit your needs for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Move it into a function to reduce duplication; note the use of prop, not attr:

```
function doDisableButton(){
    $('.search input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Call it as you have done if the value is empty:

```
if ($("li#modFilterField_34 select").val() == "") {
   doDisableButton();
}
```

Also call it when the reset button is clicked.

```
$('.search input[type="reset"]').click(function(){
   doDisableButton();
});
```

That's how to fix your code. Personally, I would handle it with jQuery validation or on form submit like so:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
    if ($("li#modFilterField_34 select").val() == "") {
        //alert user with a div, or even better use jQuery validation to handle this with a rule.
    }
});
```

The reason for that is that the user can still submit your form by hitting enter inside any textboxes inside the form with the way you are approaching it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When using `prop` the second argument better be a Boolean, at least in this case.